# How to pass a URL in params?

Tags: ruby, url

I have a url, "localhost/test/http://myimage.com/" (I'm passing myimage.com, because it's hosted on another site and I'm accessing it via an api) my question is how do I go about encoding the image portion of the URL? I thought about doing a gsub on the '.' and '/' and then gsubing them back, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `URI::encode_www_form_component(str)` and `URI::decode_www_form_component`

Check: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: Note you will have to `require 'uri'` first.

Comment: This is great, thanks Piotr. However, when I use it, I get RoutingError and from what it looks like to me it's because of the '.' that it leaves in the URL. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yeah, it's becaue normally the dot should be followed by format and Rails (cause I assume you use rails) expects format there. There are ways to overcome this, but I would recommend that you put the image url in query parameter, so that you have localhost/test?image=escaped_query.

Comment: That's great info. Thanks again Piotr!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the uri library to escape and unescape a url

```
require 'uri'
escaped = URI.escape(data, Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
```

and you can get the data back with

```
original = URI.unescape(escaped)
```